# Default Rendering Date Format

Tags: templating, 2009, vbscript

We have recently inherited a Tridion 2009 implementation and whilst restoring that database onto a new development server there is one thing that is working on the old server that isn't on the new one is that all date fields on the old server are rendered in the format yyyy-MM-dd but on the new server they are rendered as dd/MM/yyyy.

The reason why that dates are needed in yyyy-MM-dd format is for some already created date time functions in the web application.

Is there an environmental variable that set's this rendered date format?

Luckily all the fields are passed through an old school global VBScript RenderContentField function that I could parse the date depending on the field type but this is not required on the old server?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is based on the server's regional settings... but no clue how to change it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently solved a bug with a similar cause. The regional settings can be accessed via the Control Panel.

The regional settings have default values for the whole server, and also per account. You should ensure that the combination of these settings ends up with the correct result for the MTSUser account (the identity under which the SDL Tridion Content Manager COM+ application is running).

Comment: I tried this logged on as myself but it didn't do anything. Shall I do it for the MTSUser?

Comment: Yep, that was it. Logged on to the Content Manager server as MTSUser and changed the Regional Settings to the required date format, restarted the services and COM+ and it works. Do you want to tweak your answer with these specifics so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like this may be a server policy setting.  Here is a link explaining how to change update it: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/da4633e8-2df5-4095-9d7f-0d636bebcb58